# z-index not works with slider and many div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have a problem with this site: http://www.lookcommunication.it/testalessio/site7/index.html

I want show the white square with logo up than the slider

**html**

```
 <div id="box_logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
 </div>

#box_logo{width:251px; height:251px; background-color:#fff;float: left;
position: relative;left: 71px;top: -45px;z-index: -2;text-align: center; border-radius: 5px;}
```

Slider code:

```
 <div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="images/slider1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/slider2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/slider3.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.flexslider{
margin: 180px 0 60px;
background: #fff;
border: 4px solid #fff;
position: relative;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-o-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
zoom: 1;
}
```

I tried to put `z-index:-9999` in `.flexslider`, but it does not work.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Z-index for `#box_logo`

Change

```
#box_logo{ z-index:-2; }
```

to

```
#box_logo{ z-index:1000; }
```

Comment: should stand above the square and under the purple bar, not works for me

Comment: @Reverter If you want to create effect that it displays itself under the purple bar then use border-radius for bottom-left and bottom-right. There are many generators you can find on google if you don't know how to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

Like this please `add` `z-index:-2;` in below `selector`

**CSS**

```
.flexslider{
z-index:-2;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't change this behaviour. You want the logo on a higher level, hence you should give the logo a higher z-index. Flexslider gives z-indices, best not to change that behaviour, might break things in older IE's

Answer (score 0):

use `z-index: 3` in `#box_logo` and `#logo_shadow` because slide li have `zindex: 2`

```
#box_logo {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    float: left;
    height: 251px;
    left: 71px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: -45px;
    width: 251px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#logo_shadow {
    background-image: url("../img/logo_shadow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    right: 177px;
    top: 199px;
    width: 251px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use z-index:1000 on flexslider and z-index:1001 on logo.

Comment: Using a z-index on flexslider is not needed at all :) You are only expanding your css without this making a difference. Always remember KISS ("Keep It Simple Stupid") ;)

Comment: Did you see user's website? :) Talking about best-practise is a waste of time probably.
No problem anyway